# Changing paper size when printing label on Brother printer in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, printing, page-size

I have a Brother PT9800PCN which uses tapes (6 mm to 36 mm) to print labels.

In an Windows Form App I have various buttons that when clicked should print a certain file (pdf) to the printer. Depending on the file, different tapes are required. Sizes are take using values from text boxes where I specify the size I need.

My issue is, that when I specify the page size, it prints on what ever is set in the printers preferences as default.

I've set printer preferences to 18 mm size tape and 50 mm length.

I've fitted a 24 mm tape in the printer and in the code I'm setting the page size to 24x50 mm.

When I click to print, the printer flashes red that I have the wrong size tape fitted.

In the printers settings, I've also saved some custom size under different names.

Tried setting RawKind to 0 and to something higher than 119, no luck.

```
        PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument pdfiumDoc = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(file);
        PrintDocument pd = pdfiumDoc.CreatePrintDocument(PdfiumViewer.PdfPrintMode.CutMargin);
        pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = comboPrinters.SelectedItem.ToString();
        pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = new Margins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
        pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.RawKind = 0;
        //pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize.PaperName = "customSize";
        pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new PaperSize("customSize", (int)Math.Round((double)Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * 500 / 127), (int)Math.Round((double)Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text) * 500 / 127));
        pd.Print();
```

Comment: have you tried to change paper size Brother software - Printing setting tools?

Comment: also try and add this line `pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = new  PaperSize (..);`

Comment: @styx he has already that line

Comment: @sLw he have `pd.PrinterSettings.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize` and not `pd.DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize`

Comment: @sLw tried it. same thing

Comment: @styx changing the paper size in the Brother software is not what I want. Regardless of what is set in the printers preferences, I want and need to be able to set the required size. If I have by default set, lets say a 12 mm tape, in my app when I press a button, I need it to create a pdf (this works fine) and from my in app settings to choose the paper size and print on the correct tape. If I set the page size to 24mm, the printer should only flash red if I don't have a tape in of if it's the wrong size in. Don't want it to flash red because the default size tape is different.

Comment: @xlucian it might be the problem that you are using mm but papersize uses inches? try to convert your numbers to inches and try again

Comment: @sLw this piece of code (int)Math.Round((double)Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) * 500 / 127) is what it does

Comment: try printing something with word(office, or whatever) that is 24x50mm so you know if its the printers fault or your codes

Comment: @sLw printer is fine. I am able use the `PRINTUI.DLL, PrintUIEntry /Sr /n` and `PRINTUI.DLL, PrintUIEntry /Ss /n` commands to load *.dat files with printer settings to send the pdf file to the printer and this way it does work how I want it. But this requires that each user needs to save the *.dat files with custom printer settings on their PCs. The files are not transferable between PCs, don't know why. I want remove this and have the printer and page sizes, trays etc build in the app.